# Angular communication between two components using subject

Tags: angular, observable, subject-observer

I have two angular components and need to pass in an object from one component to another on a click.
My first component has the following

```
showEventDetails(event: Event) {
    this.eventsService.sendEventDetail(event)
  }
```

Here Event is my custom model object:

```
export class Event {
  id: number
  title: string
  description: string
  url: string
  date: string
}
```

The event service file is as follows:

```
export class EventsService {
  eventDetailSubject = new Subject<any>();

  constructor() {
  }

  sendEventDetail(event: Event) {
    this.eventDetailSubject.next(event);
  }

  getEventDetail(): Observable<Event> {
    return this.eventDetailSubject.asObservable();
  }
```

My Second component has the following code to receive the event data.

```
this.eventsService.eventDetailSubject.subscribe(event => {
      this.eventCal = event
      this.isLoading = false
    }, error2 => {
      this.isLoading = false
      this.hasError = true
    })
```

However, I notice that I am unable to receive the event data in the second component. What am I missing here? Is there any other way to pass on this event object from one component to another where the second component is not a child of the first one?

Answer (score 2):

RxJS `Subject` will emit only if it receives a value *after* the subscription. Instead you could use [`ReplaySubject`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/class/BehaviorSubject) with buffer size 1. It could buffer the last emitted value and emit it immediately upon subscription.

```js
export class EventsService {
  eventDetailSubject = new ReplaySubject<any>(1);
  ...
```

Comment: prefer a `ReplaySubject` in cases where there should not be a default value, as `null` could cause unexpected errors