# Subject not being triggered when changing URL

Tags: angular, angular-router, behaviorsubject, subject, subject-observer

My Application has the following `app-routing.module.ts`:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { PageNotFoundComponent } from './core/page-not-found/page-not-found.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path:  '', redirectTo: 'forms', pathMatch: 'full'  },
  { path:  'forms', loadChildren : () => import('./pages/forms/forms.module').then(m => m.FormsModule)   },
  { path:  'admin', loadChildren : () => import('./pages/admin/admin.module').then(m => m.AdminModule)   },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }  

@NgModule({
   imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
   exports: [RouterModule]
}) 
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

As you can see, I have two of what I call "products", they are "forms" and "admin", and they are acessed by the url /forms and /admin respectively.

The `app.component.html` is as follows:

```
<navbar></navbar>

<div class="container">
  <ngx-spinner
    bdColor = "rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.6)"
    size = "large"
    color = "white"
    type = "ball-running-dots">

  <p style="font-size: 20px; color: white">Loading...</p>

  </ngx-spinner>

  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>

<app-footer></app-footer>
```

As you can see, I have the component "navbar", tagged as `<navbar></navbar>`. The thing is that, the content of this navbar will vary based on the product that the user are in. To make things more clear, let's take a look in the `navbar.component.html`:

```
<default-navbar *ngIf="currentProduct == 'forms'"></default-navbar>
<div *ngIf="currentProduct != 'forms'">
    lalalallala
</div>
```

And also in the `navbar.component.ts`:

```
import { OnInit, OnDestroy, Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription } from '../../../../../node_modules/rxjs';
import { ProductEnum } from '../../../shared/models/enums/product-enum';
import { ProductContainer } from '../../../shared/containers/product-container';

@Component({
    selector: 'navbar',
    templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.scss']
  })
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy 
{
    public currentProduct:ProductEnum;

    private subscription = Subscription.EMPTY;

    constructor(private _productContainer:ProductContainer) 
    {
        
    }

    ngOnInit(): void 
    {
        this.currentProduct = this._productContainer.getCurrentProduct();
        this.initializeSubscribers();
    }

    ngOnDestroy(): void 
    {
        this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    }

    private initializeSubscribers():void
    {
        this.subscription.add(this._productContainer.getChangeCurrentProductSubject().subscribe(_newCurrentProduct => {
            this.currentProduct = _newCurrentProduct;
        }));
    }
}
```

So the navbar content will vary depending on the `currentProduct` property. And this variable will be updated by the subject property that exists on a injectable service that I called `ProductContainer` (horrible name by the way, I know).

Here is the `ProductContainer`(`product-container.ts`) code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from '../../../../node_modules/rxjs';
import { ProductEnum } from '../models/enums/product-enum';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
  })
export class ProductContainer
{
    private changeCurrentProductSubject: Subject<ProductEnum> = new Subject<ProductEnum>();

    private currentProduct: ProductEnum = ProductEnum.Forms;
    
    public setCurrentProduct(_newCurrentProduct:ProductEnum):void
    {
        this.currentProduct = _newCurrentProduct;
        this.changeCurrentProductSubject.next(this.currentProduct);
    }

    public getCurrentProduct():ProductEnum
    {
        return this.currentProduct;
    }

    public getChangeCurrentProductSubject():Subject<ProductEnum>
    {
        return this.changeCurrentProductSubject;
    }
}
```

So if we go back to the `app-routing.module.ts`, we can see the when the \admin url is acessed, the `AdminModule` is loaded. Here is the `AdminModule` code:

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { SharedModule } from '../../shared/shared.module';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AdminRoutingModule } from './admin-routing.module';
import { AdminHomeModule } from './admin-home/admin-home.module';
import { CoreModule } from '../../core/core.module';
import { ProductContainer } from '../../shared/containers/product-container';
import { ProductEnum } from '../../shared/models/enums/product-enum';
import { Router, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [],
    imports: [
      CommonModule,
      SharedModule,
      AdminRoutingModule,
      AdminHomeModule,
      CoreModule,
      RouterModule
    ]
})
export class AdminModule
{
  constructor(private _productContainer:ProductContainer, private router: Router)
  {  
    this._productContainer.setCurrentProduct(ProductEnum.Admin);
  }
}
```

So, when the \admin url acessed, it will set the current product to Admin, so the navbar will have knowledge that the product has been updated.

But the issue is very simple, the subscribe inside the navbar is not being triggered.

(edit: Part of the bug was also caused by the use of `private subscription = Subscription.EMPTY;`, it stated working when I replaced with `private subscription = new Subscription();`)

Comment: It might be because the RxJS `Subject` emits only if it receives the value *after* the subscription. There was a similar question few minutes back. Try it's solution, you might have the same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62543513/6513921

Comment: @MichaelD didn't work as well. I don't think it has to do with execution order, cause even if the ```NavbarComponent``` didn't manage to subscribe in time, it will get the new value in the ```getCurrentProduct()``` method on the ngOnInit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I would like to advise moving all the logic from NgModule, this is bad practice, the module does not exist for this.

I cant understand how you want to change currentProduct, in construcor from AdminModule? This this will not work, after the first download the module will no longer load, so the constructor will not be called.

You can subscribe to url change event. In navbar component:

```
      if (this.router.url.startsWith(`/forms`)) {
               this.currentProduct = ProductEnum.Forms;
      } else if (this.router.url.startsWith(`/admin`)) {
               this.currentProduct ProductEnum.Admin;
      }

      this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
        if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
            if (event.url.startsWith(`/forms`)) {
               this.currentProduct = ProductEnum.Forms;
            } else if (event.url.startsWith(`/admin`)) {
               this.currentProduct = ProductEnum.Admin;
            }
        }
      })
```

But if I were you, I would define the "page type" (admin or forms or something else) parameter in navbar and transfer this navbar to the root pages of the modules and also make an outlet for child pages (so as not to add navbar to each page)

Just in case use BehaviorSubject instead Subject

Comment: I tried to add in the initializeSubscribers method inside the navbar: ```this.subscription.add(this._router.events.subscribe(event => {
            debugger;
            if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
                if (event.url.startsWith(`/forms`)) {
                   this._productContainer.setCurrentProduct(ProductEnum.Forms);
                } else if (event.url.startsWith(`/admin`)) {
                   this._productContainer.setCurrentProduct(ProductEnum.Admin);
                }
            }
        }))```. And it didn't fall into the debugger.

Comment: I think in the component we no longer make sense to access the service and you can just do this: `this.currentProduct = ProductEnum.Admin` or ProductEnum.Forms. 
If this didnt work plese show me log of event inside if block

Comment: I put the debugger inside the ```router.events```, I dont think it will make much difference, cause the event is not even being triggered. I think this happens because the whole application is being reloaded when I update the URL. And this includes the navbar component, so the component will be rebuild as well.

Comment: Okay, I forgot to add that for the first time it shouldn’t work (only for changes), please add this before subscribing to url (update in post)

Comment: The issue now is that ```this._router.url``` content is just "/" instead of "/forms" or "/admin", even though the url is /forms or /admin. Do you have any idea why this happens?

Comment: It gets harder to research, could you fill in your example on stackblitz

Comment: Sure, I will do it in a sec

Comment: Hey sry for the late response, but now it's working, the issue with the ```this._router.url``` was solved in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45320416/angular-router-url-returns-slash. So I just implemented the method like this: ```if (this._location.path().startsWith(`/forms`))
        {
            this.currentProduct = ProductEnum.Forms;
        }
        else if (this._location.path().startsWith(`/admin`)) 
        {
            this.currentProduct = ProductEnum.Admin;
        }```

Comment: Thank very much, it was afterall a conceptual bug.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this function in your product.container.ts file,

```
public getChangeCurrentProductSubject(): Observable<ProductEnum>
{
    return this.changeCurrentProductSubject.asObservable();
}
```

and this in your navbar.component.ts file

```
ngOnInit(): void 
{
    this.initializeSubscribers();
    this.currentProduct = this._productContainer.getCurrentProduct();
}
```

also, try modifying the Subscription in navbar.component.ts file like this

```
import { Subscription } from "rxjs";
private subscription = Subscription;

this.subscription = this._productContainer.getChangeCurrentProductSubject().subscribe(_newCurrentProduct => {
         this.currentProduct = _newCurrentProduct;
        });
```

I hope this works

Comment: @GuiOliveira did you try using the ngOnInit() function as above?

Comment: The issue is now on this line ```private subscription = Subscription;```. If I do this, I cannot do this line: ```this.subscription = this._productContainer.getChangeCurrentProductSubject().subscribe(_newCurrentProduct => {
         this.currentProduct = _newCurrentProduct;
        });```. Because is of different type

Comment: I think _newCurrentProduct should be in parenthesis, 
`this.subscription = this._productContainer.getChangeCurrentProductSubject().subscribe((_newCurrentProduct) => {          this.currentProduct = _newCurrentProduct;         });`